# No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client

Tags: java, spring, email, wildfly-8

```
Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:392) [spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) [spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336) [spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at com.alesco.util.MessageThread.sendMail(MessageThread.java:143) [classes:]
        at com.alesco.service.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl.sendForgotPasswordMail(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:855) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198) [spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.sendForgotPasswordMail(Unknown Source)
        at com.alesco.controller.AuthenticationController.forgotPassword(AuthenticationController.java:266) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:769) [javax.mail-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:687) [javax.mail-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) [javax.mail-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389) [spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
```

Whith the same SMTP code in standalone app(simple java programe) runs in same machine(server)

> Wildfly server 8,
>   Java 8,
>   spring 3.2.

Snippet of code is :

```
public Mail {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;

    public void sendMail() throws Exception {

        try {

            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

            // use the true flag to indicate you need a multipart message
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

            helper.setFrom(appPropSource.getProperty("email.from"));

            helper.setTo(emailId);

            helper.setSubject(subject);

            // use the true flag to indicate the text included is HTML
            helper.setText(text, true);

            mailSender.send(message);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the same library for javax-mail is used? Application servers (like wildfly) have their own javax-mail library. Are you sure that you use the same library in your standalone program?

Comment: Can you post your mail properties so that we can guess what it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thakyou guys for your inputs,

**This is my snippet of code**

**Write like**

Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

**insted of **

Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
{
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
{ return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password); }
});

**Write like this in spring code:**

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="xx.xxx.xxx" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
<prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
**insted of** 
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="xx.xxx.xxx" />
<property name="port" value="587" />
<property name="username" value="xxx@xx.com" />
<property name="password" value="xxxxx" /> 
<property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
<prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
<prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

Thanks,
Govardhan Rao G
```